# Using .format to turn a float to an integer

Tags: python

Very quick question.

```
x = 10
print("value is {:d}".format(x))
```

returns

```
value is 10
```

on the other hand:

```
x = 10.0
print("value is {:d}".format(x))
```

returns

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'
```

Why doesnt this work?

Comment: Use this instead `print("value is {:f}".format(x))` https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1):

You would use `f` not `d` for floats. And then specify the precision width as 0:

```
>>> print("value is {:.0f}".format(x))
value is 10
```

Answer (score 1):

From Python docs: `'d' Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.`
It will output the number in base 10, thats why you are getting the `ValueError`.